# Unable to install Ableton 9 via POL in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine, playonlinux

I try to install and use Ableton 9.6. with PlayOnLinux, and even as the installation went smooth, every time I try to start it, it crashes and shows the following error:

```
Error in main. Ableton 9 Suite is crashed.
```

Here's some information from the log when trying to run it:

```
[08/30/16 19:56:36] - Running wine- Ableton Live 9 Suite.exe (Working directory : /home/esturoy/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Ableton/drive_c/users/Public/Application Data/Ableton/Live 9 Suite/Program)
err:module:import_dll Library mfc120u.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\Public\\Application Data\\Ableton\\Live 9 Suite\\Program\\Ableton Live 9 Suite.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library MSVCR120.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\Public\\Application Data\\Ableton\\Live 9 Suite\\Program\\Ableton Live 9 Suite.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library MSVCP120.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\Public\\Application Data\\Ableton\\Live 9 Suite\\Program\\Ableton Live 9 Suite.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\users\\Public\\Application Data\\Ableton\\Live 9 Suite\\Program\\Ableton Live 9 Suite.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Ableton is the only reason for me to use Windows. I would be thankful any kind of suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a few required support libraries, a quick google search suggests they are from VCRuntime2013. You could try:

Open the configurator for your Ableton installation in PlayOnLinux, go to the "installed components", and install the **vcrun2013** component.

*Disclaimer: This might actually completely wreck the virtual drive you created for your Ableton installation and require you to start from scratch, but since it isn't working anyway, I guess it's worth a shot.*